# Java equivalent of ssh bash command

Tags: java, ssh, ssh-keys, private-key

I would like to execute

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=dev/null -i key.txt user@host 'cd some/directory; ./check status'
```

on Java and read the response it gives me. Can someone please tell me how I would go about doing this?
As you see from the command, the problem is that I need to execute only one command, and I am using a private key to get into the server without using any passwords or anything of the kind. Any help will be immensely appreciated, I am bashing my head against the wall trying to solve this.

Comment: Use `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);`, and use `ProcessBuilder` is the former is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Runtime and Process:

```
Process cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh -o ...");
```

Then you can process the output:

```
BufferedReader outReader = new BufferedReader(
                              new InputStreamReader(cmdProc.getInputStream()));
String l;
while ((l= outReader.readLine()) != null) {
   // process standard output here
}
```

Comment: Sorry man, your answer is absolutely right also, but I just chose @kocko due to him being more in depth.

Comment: I liked your solution better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Runtime` class and split the command into pieces, stored as element of a `String[]` array object. Then, pass this array as an argument of the [Runtime#exec(String[] args)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method, which will automatically *execute the specified command and arguments in a separate process.*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] cmd = { "/bin/ssh", "-o", "..." };
    Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
    BufferedReader is = 
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java  ProcessBuilder  to execute any commands including ssh calls.

```
//java 7

Process p = new ProcessBuilder("ssh command here", "myArg").start();
```

here is more information on process builder from O[racle Java site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)